# Replace all square brackets found in a string

Tags: php

I receive from a server some strings containing `[` and `]` before they reach the client side: I should convert them to `(` and `)`. I thought I could use `str_replace` but I feel there should be something more "compact" (that is: if I'm not wrong, I should call `str_replace` on the same string four times...).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you show sample input and output?

Comment: Look up `str_replace()` in the manual, and you will call it once. Which is probably the most "compact" way

Comment: @Rizier123: I came here because I couldn't understand the manual

Comment: What's more compact than `$newString = str_replace(["[","]"],["(",")"],$string);` ?

Comment: @apokryfos: I repeat myself: I found the docs (this time) a little bit confusing (for me, of course), so I could not find this solution myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$phrase  = "[10*[2+3]]+[5*2]+3";
$remov = array("[", "]");
$replc   = array("(", ")");
echo $newphrase = str_replace($remov, $replc, $phrase);
?>
```